# Custom.css does not get loaded in Sitecore WFFM mvc

Tags: wffm, mvc-forms

The `custom.css` and all other `css` files under Themes folder `\Website\sitecore modules\Shell\Web Forms for Marketers\Themes` gets loaded in web browser on vanilla version of Sitecore 8.1 update 3 but it does not work on my project instance. I believe the developer who worked on it before me has made some changes to pipelines which call these `css` files to load.

[image: Theme files]

[image: Sitecore]

I cannot seem to find anything related to this on internet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to load CSS from custom files you need to include into : **\Website\Views\Form\Index.cshtml**.

This is a content of the file:

```
@using Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration
@using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Html
@model Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.FormViewModel
@{
  ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = Model.ClientId;

  var styles = new List<string> { "content/themes/base/all.css", "content/Fields.css" };

  var scripts = new List<string>
  {
    "libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js",
    "libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js",
    "libs/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js",
    "libs/jquery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
    "wffm.min.js",
    "main.min.js"
  };

  if (Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Settings.EnableBootstrapCssRendering)
  {
      styles.Add("content/bootstrap.min.css");
      scripts.Add("libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js");
  }
}


@Html.RenderStyles(styles.Select(s => Constants.ScriptsBaseUrl + s).ToArray())
@Html.RenderStyles(string.Format(StaticSettings.CustomCssPath, string.Empty))
@Html.EditorFor(x => Model)
@Html.RenderScripts(scripts.Select(s => Constants.ScriptsBaseUrl + s).ToArray())
```

You can modify this line to add your custom css file :

```
var styles = new List<string> { "content/themes/base/all.css", "content/Fields.css" };
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. But originally my question is that sitecore Web forms load Default.css by default and MVC forms loads custom.css. This does not happen on the instance I am working on. The Sitecore screenshot above shows the website folder has reference to Themes field and it has an option to select different theme files e.g. Default.css, Custom.css. Left-Oriented.css etc and it does not work on my instance. I am interested in knowing what caused the Default.css and Custom.css to load by default?